# Why isn't __clang__ defined when using LLVM+Clang in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, llvm, visual-studio-2015

I installed LLVM for Windows, which includes Clang and a few other tools. It integrates with Visual Studio, and even lets me choose a "Platform Toolset" in the project properties. However, when I choose any of the toolsets that came with LLVM, `__clang__` isn't defined, and `_MSC_VER` is defined instead. How do I make `__clang__` defined when using LLVM and Clang in Visual Studio?

My Visual Studio version is the 2015 Preview (however I have also tested on 2013 with no success either), and my LLVM version is based off of SVN release 225473. I've tried `LLVM-vs2012`, `LLVM-vs2013`, and `LLVM-vs2014` as the Platform Toolset without success.

Comment: If you want to detect LLVM, check `__llvm__`. Clang is a GCC replacement, which an MSVC toolset isn't.

Comment: I am quite sure `__clang__` is also defined, at least it was last time I have tested it. Make sure you are checking `__clang__` before `_MSC_VER`.

Comment: Neither `__clang__` nor `__llvm__` are defined when using the Platform Toolset in Visual Studio. I got the toolset from http://llvm.org/builds

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this, other than defining __clang__ your own? I have a similar problem but it seems I can not add a custom definition in my environment.

Comment: @Silicomancer even I'm facing the same issue as your's can u tell me how u solved it i.e without defining clang

Comment: No, I did not find a solution.

Comment: I never figured it out as well other than just defining it myself.

Comment: At least with clang-cl 11 __llvm__ is pre-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions, add `__clang__`. Yes, this is just a workaround.

Comment: I guess I can use this for now, as at this point I'm wondering if it's just an oversight on Microsoft's part.